# rails 3.1 upgrade with backbone, can't find ujs and remotipart files

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline, ujs

I upgraded to rails 3.1.3 a few weeks ago, and moved a bunch of stuff around to use backbone.

Mostly, things are going well, but I just realized that the rails-ujs.js file and remotipart.js files are not in the assets directory.

I've looked for them in the old `public/javascripts` folder, as well as everywhere else, but no luck finding them.

I also can't seem to find the files in the git repos. Is there somewhere to download these files in Javascript? or do they need to be generated by rails? Is there a way to regenerate them?

---------------this could be my error ----------------------------

I just realized that with the assets packed, you can't just open a file from view source, they all show as non-existent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think theses files lived in the rails ujs plugins in asset directory. so you need to add it to your Gemfile and the asset pipeline should see them automaticaly.

all files here https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/tree/master/src are available to include in your js file with

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

[see plugin readme for more informations](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/blob/master/README.md)

Comment: unfortunately that isn't the issue djtal, I have that file, and like in the link you provided, it is called rails.js, not jquery_ujs. I have an entry to `require jquery_ujs`, but of course no file called that. Should I just rename rails as jquery_ujs?? And of course, this doesn't solve the mystery of the missing remotipart.js

Comment: I apologize djtal, this problem might not exist, as I may have been mi-interpreting that you can't view source and open the javascript files of the assets path.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include this in your Gemfile:

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
```

That is the official plugin for this code.

Run bundle install.

Then you add the lines:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

to you application.js file.

Comment: unfortunately that isn't the issue Richard, I have that gem, and an entry to require jquery_ujs, but the file from the gem is strangely called rails.js. Should I just rename rails as jquery_ujs?? And of course, this doesn't solve the mystery of the missing remotipart.js

Comment: I apologize Richard, this problem might not exist, as I may have been mi-interpreting that you can't view source and open the javascript files of the assets path.